# Single stroke / monoline text in Inkscape for laser engraving

Tags: inkscape, typography, laser-cutting

I'm trying to prepare a design in Inkscape to be sent to a laser cutter that should engrave some small text, with just with a single line.

Using the text tool and converting to a path gives me an *outline* of the text, which is *not* what I want.

How can I create text that uses a stroke instead of an area?

Answer (score 5):

Choose Extensions > Render > **Hershey Text...**

There are a number of fonts to choose from. Here are a couple of samples.

[image: Simple text]

[image: Bold italic serif text]

Need Inkscape 0.91 or greater.